# VHDL Case statement error

Tags: random, error-handling, vhdl, leap-year

i create a function that generate a random number. That number represent an year. I need to find if that year is a leap-year. The range of generated numbers is between 2000 and 2017, so i think that i could use an case instead of applying a formula to find the leap years.

```
architecture arh_afisare of afisare is      
signal year: integer;
signal leap_year: integer;
begin
process
begin
    year <= random_gen(2000, 2017); 
    case year is
        when '2000' => leap_year <='1';
        when '2004' => leap_year <='1';
        when '2008' => leap_year <='1';
        when '2012' => leap_year <='1';
        when '2016' => leap_year <='1';
        when others => leap_year <='0';
    end case;
wait for 100 ns;
end process;
end architecture;
```

I get this error on every line with 'when' expect the last one.

> Error: COMP96_0019: Afisare.vhd : (28, 9): Keyword 'others' expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `case` lines:

```
when '2000' => leap_year <='1';
```

`2000` is an integer, but you have put single quote marks around it. This is not a valid construct; just delete the single quotes:

```
when 2000 => leap_year <='1';
```

Per the comment, the choice of `integer` for `leap_year` is a bit strange. If you define this with type `std_logic`, your assignment of `leap_year <= '1'` becomes valid. Alternatively, if `integer` is appropriate, change the assignment to `leap_year <= 1` .

Comment: Also, change leap_year to std_logic.

Comment: @FritzDC not necessarily, we don't know the context. If it's `integer` or better, `natural range 0 to 1` you can add it to daysPerYear etc (but you'd have to lose the quotes there too)

Comment: Yes, "or lose the quotes as well" would've be in order. Having said that, while writing VHDL, using std_logic for binary logic might be a good habit to learn.